# Generic repository implementation with base repository as abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern, ef-core-3.1

net core project. I am trying to implement generic repository pattern. I have base repository which is abstract. So I am overriding base repository and creating my other repositories. The implementation looks below.

BaseRepository.cs

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository<T>: IBaseRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
       private readonly DbContext dbContext;
       private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
       public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
            this.dbSet = dbContext?.Set<T>();
        }
      public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
     }
   }
```

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<T> : BaseRepository<T>, IRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
     private readonly DbContext dbContext;
     private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
     public Repository(DbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
     public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
     }
   }
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork<TContext>
        where TContext : DbContext, IDisposable
    {
     private readonly MyContext context;
     private Dictionary<(Type type, string name), object> _repositories;
     public UnitOfWork(MyContext myContext)
        {
            if (this.context == null)
            {
                this.context = myContext;
            }
        }
     public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return (IRepository<TEntity>)GetOrAddRepository(typeof(TEntity), new Repository<TEntity>(Context));
        }
      public async Task<int> CompleteAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return await this.context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
                return await this.context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
      internal object GetOrAddRepository(Type type, object repo)
        {
            _repositories ??= new Dictionary<(Type type, string Name), object>();

            if (_repositories.TryGetValue((type, repo.GetType().FullName), out var repository)) return repository;
            _repositories.Add((type, repo.GetType().FullName), repo);
            return repo;
        }
    }
  }
```

Then In my startup.cs file when I register

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(this.Configuration["AzureSQLConnectionString"]));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

UnitofWork throws me error using the generic type 'UnitofWork' requires 1 type of argument. Then I added `services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork<MyContext>>()`. Now Its throwing error in GetAsync method in Repository.cs. The error is Parameter: source is required, it cannot be empty. Then I found

> IQueryable query = this.dbSet;

query is empty. So what I understood is I have some issues with establishing connection to db. Can someone help me what exactly I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: According to your code, you are not overriding anything. The implementation is the same in both base and derived classes, but even if it were different, you are not marking the base method as **virtual** so that it can be **overriden**. I'm just pointing that out, not that this is what you were asking.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for reminding me. I made it as virtual now. But I am having issue with dbcontext. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try making the context and dbsets protected in the base class, and get rid of the private fields in the derived class. You are only intitializing in the base class. If the code for GetAsync doesn't change, you don't need to reimplement it, but read my previous comment and mark is as virtual in case some repo needs to override it.

Comment: In Repository.cs I am getting Dbcontext as null. This is the issue but really struggling how can I fix this?

Comment: I explained why it happens in my previous comment. Your repo class is using its private context which is never initialized. It is not taking it from the base class.

Comment: I did as you said. This is working like charm. Can you please put answer? I spent 4 hours to fix this.

Comment: Where is myContext coming from in the Startup? It's hard for me to tell you what's wrong exactly. In my opinion, there is no real need to do what you are trying to do. The DbContext class is a unit of work, and the DbSet classes are repositories, so you are doing pattern over pattern here. If it's because of unit testing, there are alternatives to go about it.

Comment: I concur. Do you really need this extra layer? Did you really weigh all pros and cons? For one, it's an illusion to think you abstracted away EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these classes as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T>: IBaseRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
       protected readonly DbContext dbContext;
       protected readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

       public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
            this.dbSet = dbContext?.Set<T>();
        }
      public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = this.dbSet;
            foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
     }

public class Repository<T> : BaseRepository<T>, IRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
     
        public Repository(DbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        //override GetAsync if different than base. In your case it is not.
     }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. The idea is to have integrate app with different repositories. Currently I have only baserepository and repository. In future I will have some more repositories like repository 1,2 etc. This is what the whole idea and I am trying to achieve it. So am I in correct path?

Comment: So for above requirements I am assuming I should make methods as abstract in base repository right? because I will be having implementation in repository. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Regarding your first question, you might want to read something like [this posting](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/).  As for abstract methods, if you can't provide a default implementation then make it abstract, otherwise make it virtual and add the code as in the example.